# Xcode window positions when switching from dual to single monitor

Tags: xcode, macos, multiple-monitors

When I'm working at home I plug my MacBook in to my 20" monitor as a second (right side) monitor. I do all my editing in Xcode on the larger monitor, and leave the menu bar, debugging and documentation on the laptop's monitor.

The problem is when I disconnect from the second monitor and want to work on code in "laptop" mode. Now, whenever I open a file for editing, it shows up almost entirely off the screen and I have to drag it over to edit it. I understand (sort of) why this is happening, since I last had it open in a different monitor. What I'd like to do is reset the window positions in Xcode so the edit windows show up completely on the laptop monitor. Any ideas on how to do this?

I'd even be willing to nuke entries out of the preferences (or set up an applescript to do it) but the xcode plist is inscrutable to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the project in finder, select show package contents, and delete the two username.* files.  Its not automated... but it works.

Additionally if your using some kind of version control system you probably want to add username.* to your ignore pattern.