# Reset Xcode 4 window positions

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4

I revive a previous question, but now for Xcode 4.

How can I reset window positions for a project in Xcode 4?

The old question was:
[Xcode window positions when switching from dual to single monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390884/xcode-window-positions-when-switching-from-dual-to-single-monitor)

I've tried to delete user data files as suggested in the other question, but it didn't reset the window positions.

Comment: By the way, I managed to fix the position of my windows manually, re-enabling the toolbar which was hidden and recovering the code window which had disapeared, but being able to reset all windows with a single operation might be useful to save time in these cases...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to delete the **xcuserdata/*username*.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate** file inside the workspace bundle. You can get to it via Finder "Show Package Contents" or via the Terminal.

If you're not using a workspace, your xcodeproj will have a workspace file inside it that you can open up.

Delete the file and re-open the workspace and your window settings will be back to default.

BTW, this happens to me all the time when I accidentally leave a double-clicked file open and then close the main window.. it always comes back helpfully showing the single file with nothing else.

Comment: I can find the username.xcuserdatad folder, but it doesn't contain UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to the user data files in the project package contents?  You can try deleting User -> Library -> Preferences -> com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist.  That should reset everything.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't reset the windows and toolbars positions and visibility. Quite strange, since the plist file actually SEEMS to contain the state of the editor.

Comment: That's weird because I could have sworn it reset mine when I deleted it.  I don't know where else it would be retaining the information.

Comment: It did reset my Xcode installation, including the missing toolbars. Perhaps Enrico had Xcode opened when he performed the reset.

Comment: This didn't work for me, and I definitely closed XCode before I deleted it.